# How to make a contiguous linked list?

Tags: c++, memory-management, linked-list

I have a custom data structure for a circular linked list. Its purpose is very niche, so I want to know if there is a way to make each node point to an address in a contiguous block of memory to achieve random access. The list won't be modified (inserted/deleted) at all after initial population, so a contiguous block isn't hindering anything I don't think.

How can I achieve this?

Also, the reason why I'm not using a vector is because I'm performing a rotation on the list based on pointer rearrangement. However, I'm rearranging the pointers by O(n), whereas I believe I can rearrange the pointers by O(1) via pointer arithmetic if I use a contiguous memory space.

Edit for more clarity:
My "list" is like so

```
// barebones circular list structure
class List
{
    private:
        struct Node
        {
            Node* next;
            int data;
        };

        // beginning of list
        Node* start;
        // end of list which POINTS to beginning as well
        Node* end;
        // number of list elements
        int size;

    public:
        List()
        {
            start = NULL;
            end = NULL;
            size = 0;
        }
        ~List();

        // populates the list using size parameter and uses stdin for the values
        void populate_list(const int &size);
        // moves the starting pointer of a list, effectively rotating it
        void move_start(int n, char d);
        // print contents of list
        void print();
};
```

As I have said, all of the elements (nodes) of the list are populated via populate list. The convention for population is sequential starting from 1. So you are given a size of let's say 5, the list populates like {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Then, given an amount to rotate the list, I rotate via `move_start()`

```
// moves starting node by n spaces in d direction
void List::move_start(int n, char d)
{
    // left rotation procedure
    if (d == 'L')
    {
        // move the start pointer the given rotation amount
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            start = start->next;
    }

    // right rotation procedure
    else if (d == 'R')
    {
        // move the start pointer by the size of the list minux the given rotation amount
        for (int i = 0; i < size-n; i++)
            start = start->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

Maybe my understanding is wrong, but I believe I am "rotating" at O(n) since I am walking the `start` pointer anywhere from 1 to `size-1` times (. But if I were to have a contiguous block of `Node`s, then I could simply assign `start` to a new position instead of walking it there (O(1)). Hope that clears things up.

Comment: If you want to make your nodes contiguous then why not just use an array or a vector?

Comment: The correct answer is "use a vector" but you can do this by allocating a block of memory of the appropriate size and using placement `new`.  You're really just getting a more memory hungry `vector` at that point though.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 The reason why I'm not using a vector is because I'm performing a rotation on the list based on pointer rearrangement. However, I'm rearranging the pointers by O(n), whereas I believe I can rearrange the pointers by O(1) via pointer arithmetic if I use a contiguous memory space.

Comment: @JamesNewman FYI --Before languages that use pointers were widely in use, linked lists were implemented using arrays of data/next pairs, where the "next" would be the index to where the next node was located in the linked list.  I don't know if this is an option for you, but that's how it was done.  At least, you would get the contiguous nature you are looking for.

Comment: Using an `std::vector` in your case is dangerous, because it may invalidate all pointers when it is resized. In your question, you state that this won't happen after initial population. Therefore, in order to prevent a resize during initial population, you can call [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) before initial population. Or you can simply use `new` to allocate an array of nodes (or use [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) if you want RAII behavior).

Comment: Requirements are unclear. Rationale is unclear. To me, maybe something like a `deque`, but I am not sure.

Comment: You can define a custom allocator for use with std::list.

Comment: "I'm rearranging the pointers by O(n), whereas I believe I can rearrange the pointers by O(1) via pointer arithmetic" This is a rather mysterious statement. Can you show some code?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  I've edited the original post for clarity.

Comment: It looks like you need a circular buffer rather than a linked list.

Comment: Use a vector, and reserve a special index (the equivalent of your pointer) to indicate where the circular data starts. When you need to get the values from this circular construct, then use modular arithmetic (`index = (index + 1) % size`) to iterate through that vector starting at that special index. A rotation of that index (left or right) uses similar arithmetic.

Comment: Unless the `next` pointer sometimes points at a node other than the one immediately after it in memory, it's not doing anything useful. A circular buffer (or a vector with offset + modulo indexing) would work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I achieve this?

You could use a standard list container using a custom allocator.

> However, I'm rearranging the pointers by O(n), whereas I believe I can rearrange the pointers by O(1) via pointer arithmetic if I use a contiguous memory space.

All lists can do rotations in constant time using the `splice` operation (as long as you don't need to search for the relevant iterators). Contiguous memory space won't improve asymptotic complexity of such operation.

---

Based on your description, it seems that simply using a `std::vector` with a custom iterator to the "first" element would be a good choice of data structure. I don't see the benefit of using linked list. The vector and iterator combined essentially produce a circular buffer.

Answer (score 2):

There are many better ways to handle your requirement as mentioned in the comments to your question.

But if your requirements so much mandate you to use the list, you can control the contiguous memory using placement new. But learn all the intricacies of using placement new before using it.

Below is an example how you can achieve that.

```
    // buffer with required size
    unsigned char buf[sizeof(int) * 4];

    // placement new in buffer
    int* pInt1 = new (buf) int(2);
    int* pInt2 = new (buf + sizeof(int) * 1) int(4);
    int* pInt3 = new (buf + sizeof(int) * 2) int(6);
    int* pInt4 = new (buf + sizeof(int) * 3) int(8);

    //Test
    std::cout << pInt1 << "  " << pInt2 << "  " << pInt3 << "  " << pInt4 << std::endl;
    std::cout << *pInt1 << "  " << *pInt2 << "  " << *pInt3 << "  " << *pInt4 << std::endl;

    //Push into the list
    std::list<int*> tList;
    tList.push_back(pInt1);
    tList.push_back(pInt2);
    tList.push_back(pInt3);
    tList.push_back(pInt4);
      
    //Test
    for (auto it = tList.begin(); it != tList.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        std::cout << **it << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding this, but I'm not quite sure how I would use placement new with the `Node` data type.

Comment: Like "int" is a type, "Node" is a type.